# How to attach a pseudo-tty to a Docker container with docker-py to replicate behaviour of `docker exec -ti <container> <command>`?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I am using the most recent version of Docker Py and I have not been able to attach a pseudo-tty to an already running container so as to make sure that the behaviour of `docker exec -ti <container> <command>` is replicated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `attach` method or `attach-stream` from the docker-py.

As described in docker-py [attach](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.attach), the method is attaching tty(s) to the running container. This is similar to the native
`docker attach` [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) which is attaching the stdin, stdout and stderr to the container.

The container needs to be created with  `stdin_open = True` and `tty = true` when calling `create_container` for the `attach` to work.

Example using `attach-socket`:

pull the `debian:latest` container

```
docker pull debian:latest
```

Create the python script `test.py` as follows

```
#! python3
import docker
import os
import time

# Create container and start it
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.create_container('debian:latest', name='test', stdin_open = True, tty = True, command = 'sh')
client.start(container)

# Create communication socket
s = client.attach_socket(container, {'stdin': 1, 'stdout': 1, 'stream':1})

# Set the socket as non-blocking
s._sock.setblocking(False)

# Start communication by sending cat
os.write(s.fileno(),b'cat /etc/hosts\n')

# Since we are non-blocking, wait for a while to get the output
time.sleep(1)

# Read up-to 10000 bytes. If there are more, we can issue another read
print(os.read(s.fileno(),10000))

client.stop(container)
client.wait(container)
client.remove_container(container)
```

Now test the script. You will see the output from the command we had executed at the shell.

```
~# python3 test.py
b'cat /etc/hosts\r\n127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\r\n::1\tlocalhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback\r\nfe00::0\tip6-localnet\r\nff00::0\tip6-mcastprefix\r\nff02::1\tip6-allnodes\r\nff02::2\tip6-allrouters\r\n172.17.0.2\t48f4a5f32f48\r\n# '
```

> Note: The socket is set to non-blockin in order to avoid being blocked while waiting for the response from the container. This approach is specific to the use case.

Comment: Hey @jordanvrtanoski, thanks for your response. Unfortunately when I executed the `DockerClient(base_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock").containers.list()[0].attach("sh", stdin_open=True, tty=True)`, it did not work as `attach` takes in only 1 positional argument. `stdin_open` and `tty` do not seem to be the correct parameters for `attach` according to the documentation too.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the flags are passed when the container is created. If the container is not created with this flags (which are the `-ti`, you will not be able to attach to the container stdin, stdout).

Comment: Understood @jordanvrtanoski. But in such a state, using the `attach` function and streaming the output would lead me to only read the output and I would still be unable to send an input there as there is no way to incorporate `stdin` in `attach`. This can be helpful to get logs passively but would not quite help in active interaction with the container - like `docker exec -ti <container> <command>` allows to.

Comment: @AkashdeepDhar I added small example. I hope it helps.