# How to get command docker shell prompt from python call

Tags: python, bash, docker

I am now creating tools to assist workflow in CI/CD. One feature that I need to make is equivalent to `docker run ... /bin/bash`. It means container will be prompt for me to input command to it.

Since my CI/CD is written in Python. I pick [docker package](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html)

I have tried

```
In [4]: client.containers.run('alpine', "/bin/sh")
Out[4]: b''
In [5]: client.containers.run('alpine', "/bin/sh", detach=False)
Out[5]: b''
In [6]: client.containers.run('alpine', "/bin/sh", detach=False, stdin_open=True)
stdin_open will hang in there nothing more
```

**Question:**
How to get a container shell prompt by calling from Python?

**References**:

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

Comment: Why run a shell?  Instead of `/bin/sh`, can you just run the actual command you need to run?

Comment: It is mini project to understand python and docker sdk

Comment: @joe Check if my answer here is working for you https://stackoverflow.com/q/66328780/2816703. This will give you `tty` to the container over a socket and you can communicate with the process inside the container.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski It does not work. Terminal hang

Comment: Don't run the `/bin/sh`, just run the command. The containers is already running `/bin/bash` and opens a `tty` to it. Than in the example I send `cat /etc/hosts\n`, with the `\n` at the end.

Comment: What I need is shell prompt. I know how to run with single command

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example:

First we import the packages that we need and crate a client to the docker engine

```
import docker
import os
import time

client = docker.from_env()
```

Next step is to create a container that is prepared for attachement of a `tty` (console) for communication. The `command` parameter passed to create is telling the container to execute the `/bin/sh` as entry point. This is equivalent of starting the container with `docker run -tid`

```
container = container = client.create_container('alpine:latest',name='test', stdin_open = True, tty = True, command = 'sh')
client.start(container)
```

After we have container running with exposed `tty` we need to get a socket connection to the `tty`, and set it to asynchronous communication.

```
s = client.attach_socket(container, {'stdin': 1, 'stdout': 1, 'stream':1})

s._sock.setblocking(False)
```

Now we are ready to send commands (multiple commands) to the shell in the container by repeating the sequence of `os.write()` and `os.read()` as follows:

*sending `cat /etc/hosts`*

```
os.write(s.fileno(),b'cat /etc/hosts\n')
time.sleep(1)
print(os.read(s.fileno(),10000))
```

*sending `ls -ltr`*

```
os.write(s.fileno(),b'ls -ltr\n')
time.sleep(1)
print(os.read(s.fileno(),10000))
```

This can be repeated as much as necessary. The `time.sleep()` is required since the socket is set to non-blocking, to allow some time for the container to execute the command and start printing on the tty.

Once the communication is done, you can cleanup the containers by using

```
client.stop(container)
client.wait(container)
client.remove_container(container)
```

Using the sequence of `write` and `read` you can even create your own shell terminal by reading the command from the user and sending it to the container with `os.write`, then reading the response with `os.read` and sending it to the user.